# Integrate $\int^{\pi}_{0}\left\{\frac{\tan^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{\sin^2(x)\cdot\,\cos^2(x)}\right\}^{\frac{1}{9}}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

$\displaystyle\int^{\pi}_{0}\left\{\dfrac{\tan^2\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)}{\sin^2(x)\cdot\,\cos^2(x)}\right\}^{\frac{1}{9}}\,dx$

$\sf{\color{blue}{My\,\,approach\,}:}$

$=\displaystyle\int^{\pi}_{0}\left\{\dfrac{\tan^2\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)}{\dfrac{4\,\tan^2(\frac{x}{2})}{\sec^4(\frac{x}{2})}\cdot\,\dfrac{(1-\tan^2(\frac{x}{2}))^2}{\sec^4(\frac{x}{2})}}\right\}^{\frac{1}{9}}\,dx$

$=\displaystyle\int^{\pi}_{0}\left\{\dfrac{\sec^8\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)}{4\cdot\,\left(1-\tan^2\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)\right)^2}\right\}^{\frac{1}{9}}\,dx$

$=\displaystyle\int^{\pi}_{0}\dfrac{\sec^{\frac{8}{9}}\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)}{2^{\frac{2}{9}}\cdot\,\left(1-\tan^2\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)\right)^{\frac{2}{9}}}\,dx$

$=\displaystyle\int^{\pi}_{0}\dfrac{\sec^{\frac{-10}{9}}\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)\cdot\dfrac{1}{2}\sec^2\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)dx}{2^{\frac{-7}{9}}\cdot\,\left(1-\tan^2\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)\right)^{\frac{2}{9}}}$

If I substitute $\color{orange}{\tan\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)=t,}$  a weird expression occurs..
Help me to figure out this

Comment: Context please? It might help. If you just put up a random integral, chances are that it's unsolvable.

Comment: For anyone interested, the Weierstrass substitution makes something that looks like: $$2^{7/9}\int_0^\infty(\frac{1}{(1+t^2)^5(1-t^2)^2})^{1/9}dt$$

Comment: I was able to reduce the integral down to

$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac1{u^{2/9}} \cdot \frac1{(u+1)^{13/18}} \cdot \frac1{(1-u)^{1/2}} \ du$$

using the identity $\tan^2(x/2) = (1-\cos x)/(1 + \cos x)$ and the substitution $u = \cos x$. Mathematica gives me an exact answer for this integral, but it's not pretty: it has a ton of hypergeometric and gamma function stuff in it.

Comment: @person. Just to precise :  the Weierstrass substitution was made by Euler fifty years before

Answer (score 2):

As @person commented, using $x=2\tan^{-1}(t)$,ws have to compute
$$I=2^{7/9}\int_0^\infty\frac{dt}{\left(1-t^2\right)^{2/9} \left(1+t^2\right)^{5/9}}$$
The antiderivative is not so bad
$$\int_0^ u\frac{dt}{\left(1-t^2\right)^{2/9} \left(1+t^2\right)^{5/9}}=u\, F_1\left(\frac{1}{2};\frac{2}{9},\frac{5}{9};\frac{3}{2};u^2,-u^2\right)$$ where appears the Appell hypergeometric function of two variables.

The problem is that I cannot evaluate the limit when $u\to \infty$

Comment: I think you have to split the ingegral at $t=1$. Atm you have $1/(1-t^2)^{2/9}$ which should read $1/((1-t^2)^2)^{1/9}$.

Answer (score -3):

$I = \dfrac{{0,028 \cdot {{2,496}^3}}}{{12}} + 2 \cdot \left( {\dfrac{{0,62 \cdot {{0,052}3}}}{{12}} + 0,62 \cdot 0,052 \cdot {{1,274}2}} \right)$

Comment: Do not forget $ symbols when writing math